# Concatenate consecutive files

Tags: files, osx, video, cat

I have a list of videos in a directory that I want to concatenate.

```
Video1.mpg
Video2.mpg
.
.
.
Video35.mpg
```

I want to concatenate this in the order of their number without having to write all of them manually to the cat command.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` and [`ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate):

```
files=(Video*.mpg(n))
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf 'file %s\n' ${(qq)files}) -c copy output.mpg
```

`(n)` in `zsh` is a *glob qualifier* to sort numerically. `(qq)` is a variable expansion flag to quote with single quotes. I won't guarantee that it quotes in the exact same was as expected by `ffmpeg` if the file names contain single quotes or backslashes or newline characters.

As far as I understand, the above assumes the same codec is used in all the mpg files.

AFAICT, for `mpeg` files specifically, the files can also be concatenated at the file level and still playable by most players, so you can also simply do (still with `zsh`):

```
cat Video*.mpg(n) > output.mpg
```

While `zsh` is installed by default in macOS, it is not the default shell you get in a terminal unless you've explicitly changed your login shell from the default of `bash`. So you'd need to either start `zsh` first, by entering `zsh` at the prompt of the `bash` shell in the terminal, or run:

```
zsh -c 'cat Video*.mpg(n) > output.mpg'
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bash brace expansion.

```
cat Video{{1..9},{10..35}}.mpg > outputfile
```

In the future, use `0` padding when naming the files originally, so you can just do:

```
cat Video{01..35}.mpg > outputfile
```

Comment: Gets me a 'No such file or directory' error.

Comment: @medicengonzo, then you don't have all the files 1 to 35 and you should [**edit your question.**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/351514/edit)  Or use file globs to only catch the files actually present: `cat Video[1-9].mpg Video[0-9][0-9].mpg > outputfile`  (Globs expand only to existing files; brace expansion is for arbitrary text arguments whether names of existing files or not.)

Comment: Since the question was tagged OSX, I'll just note that the `{01..35}` expansion doesn't work on bash 3.2.57, which is what my Mac seems to have by default..

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way:

```
cat $(ls Video*.mpg | sort -to -k2 -n )>outputfile
```

`ls Video*.mpg` - lists files based on pattern
`sort -to -k2 -n` - sorts the files using `o` as a delimiter, 2nd key, and `-n` for numeric

*Please realize, using `ls` on an unknown list of files can be unpredictable, but this is a relatively small and known list, based on the question.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer you just deleted.  Parsing `ls` [is still bad practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943), even if it sometimes works.

Comment: My previous answer was `cat $(ls Video*.mpg | sed -e "s/Video//" | sort -n | sed -e "s/^/Video/")>outputfile` - I simplified it by removing the `sed` commands, leaving a just the `sort`.  I realize using `ls` on an unknown list of files can be unpredictable, but this is a relatively small and known list based on the question.

Comment: Fair enough, that is true.  I regard this site as a learning resource and important place to promote best practices—but if you include a disclaimer to the effect of your comment I'd remove the downvote.  (Answers here get read and used long, long after the original asker has moved on.)  Or I can add a disclaimer, if you like.